# Discovering Local Network Devices & IPs Programmaticaly

Tags: java, android, multithreading, networking, ip

I'm trying to make a project that must make me able to find local devices in same network and information regarding their IPs,mac addresses and vendors.Everything is good so far but question is I relaized that by this code ,it only discovers to mobile phones and somehow doesnt see my laptops ? I tested this code and it only shows my tablet and phones but no computers.If  u have any suggestion pls let me now.Thanks in advance.And here is my code belove.

```
//This class is my pinger class

public class DiscoverRunner implements Runnable {
private List<InetAddress> results;

private String subnet;
private Integer startAdd;
private Integer numAdds;

public DiscoverRunner(String subnet, Integer start, Integer steps) {
    this.subnet = subnet;
    this.startAdd = start;
    this.numAdds = steps;
    results = new LinkedList<InetAddress>();
}




@Override
public void run() {


    int timeout=4000;
       for (int i=startAdd;i<startAdd+numAdds;i++){

           String host=subnet +"." + i;
           try {
               InetAddress a = InetAddress.getByName(host);


            if (a.isReachable(timeout)){

                results.add(a);
                //System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
               }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }

}

public List<InetAddress> getResults(){
    return results;
}
```

}

And here is my another class where i Handle threads to execute

```
public class Pinger {

private static final int NUMTHREADS = 254;
public static String myMacAddress = "";

public static ArrayList<Device> getDevicesOnNetwork(String subnet) throws IOException {
    LinkedList<InetAddress> resAddresses = new LinkedList<InetAddress>();
    DiscoverRunner[] tasks = new DiscoverRunner[NUMTHREADS];

    Thread[] threads = new Thread[NUMTHREADS];


    //Create Tasks and treads
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++) {
        tasks[i] = new DiscoverRunner(subnet,i,1);
        threads[i] = new Thread(tasks[i]);
    }
    //Starts threads
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++) {
        threads[i].start();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++) {
        try {
            threads[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++) {
        for (InetAddress a : tasks[i].getResults()) {
            try {
                a = InetAddress.getByName(a.getHostAddress());

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            resAddresses.add(a);
        }

    }

    ArrayList<Device> foundDev = new ArrayList<Device>(resAddresses.size());


    for (InetAddress a : resAddresses) {
        foundDev.add(new Device(a.getHostAddress(), getMacFromArpCache(a.getHostAddress()), a.getCanonicalHostName(), getVendorName(getMacFromArpCache(a.getHostAddress()))));
    }


    return foundDev;
}

/**
 * Try to extract a hardware MAC address from a given IP address using the
 * ARP cache (/proc/net/arp).<br>
 * <br>
 * We assume that the file has this structure:<br>
 * <br>
 * IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
 * 192.168.18.11    0x1         0x2         00:04:20:06:55:1a     *        eth0
 * 192.168.18.36    0x1         0x2         00:22:43:ab:2a:5b     *        eth0
 *
 * @param ip
 * @return the MAC from the ARP cache
 */
public static String getMacFromArpCache(String ip) {


    if (ip == null) {
        return null;
    }

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {


        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(" +");


            if (splitted != null && splitted.length >= 4 && ip.equals(splitted[0])) {
                // Basic sanity check
                String mac = splitted[3];

                if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                    return mac;

                } else {
                    return null;

                }
            }


        }
        return myMacAddress;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}


public static String getVendorName(String MacAddress) throws IOException {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://api.macvendors.com/" + MacAddress);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        String vendorName = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");


        return vendorName;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {


        return null;
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {

        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: are you accessing the network wireless? Then it maybe that other computers are connected from LAN, can you check if the subnet you provide encapsulates LAN subnet.

Comment: @sgpalit yes I'm accessing to access point (wireless adapter) in my home.and my  laptop is also accessing with wifi no ethernet connected.

Comment: @sgpalit btw, my laptop's local IP is 192.168.1.5 and as u can see from above it pings from 1 to 255, I cant understand why it cant find it in such circumstance

Comment: Maybe your firewall prevents it?

Comment: @sgpalit bro u mean firewall in my own laptop? because I opened another laptop in home, and program couldnt find other laptop too..

Comment: Yes check your firewalls on your laptops... Normally it should work :) should not it?

Comment: @sgpalit I just enabled it but result is still same :/ I dont know what to do bro,this is killing me , I have no idea how can it ping to other phones but not laptopts

Comment: @sgpalit and I think problem is probably in my code because I downlaoded some other apps which in fact detected the laptops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this ping as you do on command line, maybe you can change your coding style.

```
try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = rt.exec("ping 192.168.0.142");

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            p.destroy();
            break;
        }
        input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: bro thanks so much for your help but I didnt get what you mean exactly? because ı dint share my whoel code here and all those recycler views and stuff like that so how did it totally work? and when u run this, did u try it on your phone and it also found your laptop? what do u suggest me to do now bro?

Comment: Hi bro, I just figured out something.. we just downloaded same project to my friends computer and when we run it, it works absolutely fine and detects everything,but when we do same ın my network laptops just doesnt show up :D weird a.f :D

Comment: :)) thats good news... your code works :)) maybe it is time to change your laptop :P